# Where's iOS 4.2 image file?

Tags: itunes, ios, data-transfer, upgrade, developer-program

On Apple Developers portal, under downloads I get this:

[image]

**Where are the iPhone 3G / 4 / iPad versions of the OS?**

As I had beta 2 on my iPad (I'm have a iOS developer account), and I want to update to the new one, iTunes says iPad has version 4.2 (witch is right, 4.2b) and mentions, that there is no newer version.

Comment: Had the same problem. My iPad has an expired beta (8C5115C) but iTunes won't download an update because "4.2 is the current version."

I feel like I'm dealing with Microsoft. WTF do I have to rely on 3rd party sites that could be bootleg images to work around their developer program?

Oh and +1 to balexandre's suggestion. After verifying that they were actually Apple links I was able to download an image and get my iPad working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it here

http://tipsneeded.com/download-ios-42-ipsw/

weird that is not available in the Portal itself :(

Comment: It's not available on the portal because they expect you to get the update via iTunes. It's how they always do it: once it's out of beta you can no longer download the image. Still, weird that iTunes wouldn't update you.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick it doesn't cause it's already version 4.2, they are doing updates my major version and not by build version :( - I sent a feedback to Apple regarding this though.

Comment: Except that I have many dev friends who installed the beta 4.2 and then iTunes updated their devices to the full 4.2 when it was released. I think the problem is restricted to you, or at least a small subset of devs.

Comment: @Matthew, don't be like that.. drewish had the same problem, don't say that "I have  friend that happen this and that", We're here to help, share your own stuff!

Comment: I'm not dismissing your problem, I'm certain that you're legitimately having it. I'm merely pointing out that it appears to be limited to some people, not something that all devs are experiencing. That way when people visit this topic in the future they'll have all the information.

Answer (score 1):

4.2.1 is the newest version, and it's no longer in beta. So that means you get it through iTunes, by syncing your device and clicking the "Check for Update" button. There won't be images in the Developer Portal until Apple decides to put the next version of iOS (4.3?) into beta.

Comment: but if you have a beta version, that version is already 4.2.x and it won't be updated by iTunes!

Answer (score 0):

An iOS image file (also called IPSW short for iPhone Software file) for publicly released version of iOS can be obtained unofficially from [IPSW](https://ipsw.me).

The OS images are signed and verified with Apple servers when attempting a restore via iTunes. Do note that Apple stops signing older releases sometime (usually a couple weeks) after releasing a new iOS update. Hence, this method can be used to restore an iOS device to latest public release of iOS in cases as the one discussed in the question.